# Sending data from Django view to Django form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a Django view and I want to send the request data to a form.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Post
    form = CommentForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PostDetailView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user.username
        return kwargs

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = self.get_object()
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("post-detail", args=[post.pk]))
```

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment
from djrichtextfield.widgets import RichTextWidget

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    user = forms.ChoiceField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].choices = self.user

    content = forms.CharField(widget=RichTextWidget(attrs={
        'class': 'md-textarea form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Comment here ...',
        'rows': '4',
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'content',)
```

```
<form method="POST" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{form | safe}}
                            </div> 
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Comment</button>   
                        </form>
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
]
```

According to the docs, get_form_kwargs allows key-value pairs to be set in kwargs. The kwargs is then passed into the form. The form's **init** function should then be able to pick up the user value from kwargs.

However, self.user returns None, and debugging showed that get_form_kwargs did not run at all.

I have two questions: how do functions in view classes get executed? And what is the correct method to pass data from a view to a form?

***EDIT***
I have refactored the comment feature into another view.

```
class AddCommentView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form = CommentForm
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = self.get_object()
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("post-detail", args=[post.pk]))
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PostDetailView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.pop('instance', None)
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user.username
        return kwargs
```

```
<form method="POST" href="{% url 'add-comment' post.id %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{form | safe}}
                            </div> 
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Comment</button>   
                        </form>
```

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('post/<int:pk>/', AddCommentView.as_view(), name="add-comment")
]
```

However UpdateView cannot handle POST requests (405).

Answer (score 2):

It's not explicitly described in the docs but `get_form_kwargs` is only triggered with a `CreateView` or an `UpdateView`.

In your case you can use `UpdateView`, and then use `form_valid` to do your post process. But note that we need to delete `kwargs['instance']`, because by default this view will think we are working with a `Post` object when in fact it's a `Comment`:

Try with this:

```py
class PostDetailView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form = CommentForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PostDetailView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        # Remove the post object as instance, 
        # since we are working with a comment
        kwargs.pop('instance', None)
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user.username
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        instance.post = self.get_object() # returns the post
        instance.save()
        return redirect(reverse("post-detail", args=[post.pk]))
```

or if you don't want to use `UpdateView` (not recommended), you can just explicitly call `get_form_kwargs` when you build your form. You cannot call `super().get_form_kwargs()` though, since as discussed the parent class doesn't have this method:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    form = CommentForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = {'user': self.request.user.username}
        return kwargs

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, **self.get_form_kwargs())
        if form.is_valid():
            post = self.get_object()
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("post-detail", args=[post.pk]))
```

Lastly, do consider renaming this class, since we are working with adding a comment to post, and not really about "post detail", so something like `PostAddCommentView`?

Comment: Hi bdbd, thanks for your suggestions. PostDetailView originally only renders each post. But as the project scope increases I just added the comment feature to the view. Maybe I should refactor the comment feature into another view?

Comment: That would be better, as detail view is for getting the details about an object, not adding objects to it, etc (hence my last comment about changing the class name)

Comment: I refactored the comment feature to AddCommentView, subclassing UpdateView. But then I can't make any POST calls. How do I use AddCommentView to add a new comment to the same template?

Comment: How did you make post calls before with `PostDetailView`? Is it using ajax? Also have you added this new view to a url?

Comment: No I am not using Ajax. The template just calls the url, which calls the PostDetailView.

Comment: It seems you haven't added the new view to a new url?

Comment: That is just the original url_patterns and template for reference. I did not add any new mods to the code.

Comment: In your template change the form's `href` to `action`

Comment: Still getting 405s when trying to add comment using AddCommentView. However, if I just add post() inside PostDetailView then there is no issue with adding Comments to PostDetailView.

Comment: Did you this exactly: `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'add-comment' post.id %}">`

Comment: yes, and the form does not get called with action at all...

Comment: does UpdateView have an implementation of post()? bc the post() AddCommentView but works just fine inside PostDetailView()

Comment: Yes have a look [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/edit.py#L197). `UpdateView` inherits from `BaseUpdateView`, and as you can see in line 192 in `BaseUpdateView`, post is used.

Comment: How about you try calling this API via postman or curl? Just suspecting there is something wrong in the template

Comment: So I used Postman to track the request, using the add-comment href/action. I got a 403, which is strange because I added the CSRF token inside the form already.